# Process Group Leader's PID reused

Tags: process-groups

Is it possible that a past Progress Group Leader's PID gets reused by an other process and this latter process starts a new Process Group?
In this case the first created process group and the second one have the same PGID, which situation should be avoided I consider.
Does Linux avoid assigning a PID which is a valid PGID?

Comment: Related (but not duplicate): [Two processes with identical PID after a fork call](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/508508/86440).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not possible. It's forbidden by the [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html):

> The *fork()* function shall create a new process. The new process
>        (child process) shall be an exact copy of the calling process
>        (parent process) except as detailed below:
>
> - The child process shall have a unique process ID.
> - The child process ID also shall not match any active process group
>        ID.

Comment: There’s also some interesting discussion in [the rationale](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xbd_chap11.html#tag_21_11_01_02).